# Overfilled the engine oil by 400 ml

Tags: engine, oil, oil-change, damage

I own a Suzuki Swift diesel. The engine is Fiat MultiJet 1.3 with engine oil capacity of 3.1 litres and I poured in 3.5 litres and drove for about 50 miles. Will this hurt my car's engine ?

Comment: What does the dip stick say? Is the level above max?

Comment: It is about 1cm above the max mark. I have drained out the excess oil and wanted to know the amount of damage it would have done while there was excess oil ? Thanx for prompt response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be absolutely no damage done to your engine. A little bit too much (and when I say a little bit, .4l of oil is a little bit ... an entire liter of oil would be too much) is not going to be a problem. You've not created any issues and you've drained the excess. You're golden.

Comment: Thanx for the prompt response. I wanted to tell that the engine is a small 1248cc diesel from Fiat. Isn't .4 L overfill too much for it and driving it for 50 miles with occasional over revs to redline wouldn't damage it ?

Comment: Should not be an issue. 1/2 a liter of oil really isn't that much oil. There is more than enough room in the pan to accommodate, even on the smallest of vehicle engines (a small engine in a lawn mower would be a different story). The only real issue with overfilling is if the oil gets high enough to allow the crankshaft to impact it. This causes a whole level of  issues. Really, there should be nothing for you to worry about now.

Comment: Thanx a lot! Thats a great relief for me. Its a new car and I care too much about my car.

Comment: If you believe this answers your question, please consider clicking the checkmark and upvoting if you desire.

Comment: I am new to stackexchange. My upvotes aren't considered....:P